# Google Api Ruby Client to return the actual HTTP response, not the helper object

Tags: ruby, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

Is there an easy way to ask the google api ruby client to just give you back the stock HTTP response, rather than to perform the lovely, but slightly limiting translation into one of their ruby representable objects?

e.g.

```
response = Gmail.client.get_user_message("me", id) 

=> #<Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message

response = Gmail.client.list_user_messages("me")    
=> #<Google::Apis::GmailV1::ListMessagesResponse
```

but

```
response = Gmail.client.delete_user_message("me", id)
=>nil #successfully deleted
```

Now that's all fine and dandy, except that sometimes I just want to know what sort of response is going to come back. i.e. an HTTP response with maybe some JSON in the body. And then I'll worry about what I do with it...

I can take the response and use the

```
response.to_json
```

to get the body of the json that would have come back (though I still won't have the response code, and I need to KNOW that it's one of those objects first).

The client library is definitely getting that, it's just converting it into these objects before it lets me see it. And if I don't know that it's a google object (and not nil) I can't run that to_json consistently....

Any ideas other than second guess what google is going to send me back?
(I should note that this has come about when trying to move a library from dealing with their 0.8 api to their 0.9 api, so call me a cynic if you must but my faith that google won't make breaking changes to those objects returned is at a low ebb...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is possible to ask the server to send only the fields you really need and get a partial response instead of the default full response as mentioned in [Performance Tips](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/performance).

However, I suggest that you please check the documentation for the specific API you are using to see if the field you're looking for is currently supported. For the Gmail API, you may go through [Working with partial resources](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance#partial).

Here are the two types of partial requests that you can use:

- [Partial response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance#partial-response): A request where you specify which fields to include in the response (use the `fields` request parameter).
- [Patch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance#patch): An update request where you send only the fields you want to change (use the PATCH HTTP verb).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. The issue is not about what the API itself sends back to a vanilla API call. It's what the ruby API client is returning. Behind the scenes it's definitely picking up the JSON, but it returns a proprietary object. (Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.....) not the JSON response from the API. as standard. Was wondering if it was possible to say to the API client 'Please send me the original unprocessed response?'.